# vim Editing - how to edit the highlighted segment of a search or convert to visual block

Tags: vim

In vim, if I have the following text:

> hello there

Say I search for hell in the text above.

> /hell

and press n to move to the next instance.

> `hell`o

hell is now highlighted in vim and my cursor is on the 'h'.

What is the most efficient way to now yank/delete that highlighted text.

Is there a way to 'yank to the end of the highlighted text'?
Or 'create visual block from highlighted text'?

I know I can use %s/hell/whatever/gc to step through as an alternative.

TIA Tom

Comment: There is a tip in the Vim Tip's wiki that explains how to do that, it seems like this is not built-in: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_the_search_results_into_clipboard

Answer (score 9):

`y//e`, or `d//e` should do the trick.

`:let @" = @/` as well, even if you have moved the cursor.

Comment: I didn't know that: this is a better way of doing it than my suggestion!

Comment: Actually, they are not that different: the previous searched pattern can be omitted thanks to `//` as you already knew for `:s`, and when searching, `/e` & co replace `\zs`& co.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a built in mapping (**Edit**: but see Luc Hermitte's answer below as that's a much better solution than my bodges **End Edit**), but you could do the yank or select with a couple of mappings:

```
nmap ,y y/<C-R>/\zs<CR>
nmap ,v v/<C-R>/<BS>\zs<CR>
```

The `,y` mapping uses the '/' register to pull in the last search term search, adds `\zs` to make the search point be the end and the yank proceeds up to that point.  The `,v` mapping does a visual selection, but has to delete the last character of the search (with `<BS>`) to make it end at the right place.

For what it's worth, you can simplify the `%s/hell/whatever/gc` that you suggested by refining your search with `/` and then using a shortened form:

```
/hell
:%s//whatever/gc
```

This is because `:s` uses the last search term by default.